# EF 6 stored procedure get out variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with EF 6. I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which returns a value of type `varbinary(max)` from a table:

```
PROCEDURE [pr_Service_Get]
    (@file_id uniqueidentifier,
     @file_content varbinary(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @file_content = (SELECT file_content 
                         FROM ... 
                         WHERE id = @file_id)
END
```

And I have this C# code:

```
var output = new ObjectParameter("file_content", typeof(byte[]));

using (var ctx = _dbContext)
{
    ctx.pr_Service_Get(file_id, output);
}

return (byte[])output.Value;
```

The problem is output value is always empty. However if I execute this stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, I get the correct value back.

Also I was looking in SQL Server Profiler to see what gets sent to SQL Server. The query was correct and return correct value.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You use edmx or code first ?

Comment: ArDumez, I use edmx